# Websphere/Oracle 11 - much more Heap Usage than with Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, websphere

while testing our application with Oracle 11 (previously, we had Oracle 10), we saw that our server uses much more heap space.

It seems as it has something to do with T4CConnection/T4CPreparedStatement; there are 500 objects of T4CPreparedStatement allocated. Someone told me, that Oracle 11 is using SoftReferences to keep the connection pool; but we don't need that.

Is that correct? Could that be the problem for the increased heap space? If yes - how can we avoid connection pooling?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

During migration to Oracle 11, what else have you upgraded?
Have you upgraded the JDBC driver?
In WebSphere, did you also change the "WebSphere Helper Class" associated with the data source?

The answers to these questions may have something to do with the problem you're experiencing. Have you checked the statement pool size, for example?